# How to scale polygon while maintaining position around circle

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry

If I had the following figure shown below and I wanted to scale the top rectangle by some factor such that the left side will still touch the circle like it does now, how would I go about doing that? This is being done in C++ where the rectangles are represented by four vertices and the circle is represented by a center and radius.

To scale, I simply multiply all the vertices by the scale factor but then I need to translate the rectangle back so it still touches the circle. I'm not sure how to do the translation.

Thanks.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the point at which the circle is touching the rectangle. You can do this by working out the angle of one of the long rectangle edges that is parallel with the line from the center of the circle to the point where it touches the rectangle. Take the x and y values of the far corner and subtract the near corner x and y from them. Then the angle is

angle = atan2(y difference, x difference).

Then use that along with the circle center and circle radius to calculate the point where they touch:

touch.x = center.x + cos(angle) * radius;
touch.y = center.y + sin(angle) * radius;

Then, for each corner point of the rectangle:

- Subtract the touch point from the rectangle corner point
- Multiply by the scale value
- Add the touch point

This scales the rectangle around the touch point, so the touch point is itself unaffected.